# angularJs redirect using both $window and $location

Tags: angularjs, redirect, window, location

I try to save some value in a rootscope variable and then I want to be redirected to an other page in which I show the rootscope value .. but when I use $window.location.url='path_to_new_page'I lose all rootscope variables .. I try to do this whit $location.path('path_to_new_page') but this time I m not redirected I stay in the same page and the url doesn't change ?!

The same code work very fine in an other pc but in my pc (which I just formatted ) doesn't work .. I ve installed node js globally and also bower.

**Edit** 
Here an example of a function in my project

```
 $scope.showDetails=function(id){
        $scope.essayeREST=new RestApi('showdetails');
        $scope.essayeREST.get(id).then(function(result){
            $rootScope.user=result;

            $rootScope.firstName= $rootScope.user.firstname
            $rootScope.lastName= $rootScope.user.lastname;
            $rootScope.cn= $rootScope.attestation.user.cn;

           $window.location.url='/myApp/#/app/user_profile'
         //$location.path('/myApp/#/app/user_profile');

        });
```

Can someone help me to resolve this problem please?

Comment: other page or other state? also this must not be computer-related)) Try creating some example in plunker.

Comment: All the redirection which comes from function have the same result .. I think that it is related to computer because it's work so fine in an other one.. I try to write some code in my question

Comment: @PetrAveryanov Thanks for your unswer I just add an example of code to my question

Comment: You may want to read the docs for $location https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location .  Pay close attention to HTML5 mode, this may be what is tripping you up.